# "Move" refactoring in IntelliJ doesn't works with input

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide, refactoring, python-import

I am using Python plugin to handle Python code inside an IntelliJ Java project.

I have selected refactoring "Move -> move everything to another directory..." but it doesn't update the imports!

Example, I have:

```
import my_server.my_project.helpers.cumulative_functions as cf
```

That instead should be now

```
import my_project.helpers.cumulative_functions as cf
```

Have I done something wrong? Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common in `PyCharm` and `IntelliJ`

The problem here is working directory and run/debug config

Even when you move files, wd stays the same

It is a confirmed bug, but it's not still fixed

You can vote for [it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38653) to be fixed faster

Comment: But I am not talking about run/debug config, I am talking about the Python's imports.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i was thinking about other renaming issue. But, anyways it's just imperfection of "Rename". We just need to wait